# How to download older version of VSCode portable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So far I have only seen download links to installable versions of older VSCode in the documentation (example : we can download 1.8.1 installable version [here](https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.8.1/win32/stable) , while the latest version is 1.9.1). Is there any way to get portable versions of older builds of VSCode ?

Comment: After report this *behaviour* as an issue [on github vscode repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60933), somebody gave me the provisory link and previous archives (zip) versions will be put available asap issue come to be solved.

VSCode 1.25.1 archive (zip) Win64 link: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.25.1/win32-x64-archive/stable

Comment: @sdlins, nice post, this should be the answer to this question, could you post it as an answer? So it's easier for people looking for it. I could post it, but I prefer that you take the credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Comming soon**

After report that *behaviour* as [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60933) on github vscode repository, somebody gave me the provisory link and previous archives (zip) versions will be put available asap issue come to be solved.

VSCode 1.25.1 archive (zip) Win64 link:

- [vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.25.1/win32-x64-archive/stable](https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.25.1/win32-x64-archive/stable)

Comment: Asking for third party resources is off topic on SO so you should not be answering this question but, instead, voting to close it.

Comment: We don't answer questions asking for download links or other off-site resources here. See the [help/on-topic] if you're unsure of what is on-topic here.

Comment: @Rob I didn't know. Could you give me a source about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I did not downvote you but I will if I am to be blamed for it.